# Redirecting to a website's subdirectory based on incoming URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have two websites; site1.com and site2.com.

I have both set up with the same A Records - leading to the same server/site. However, for site2.com, I'm looking to redirect to a subdomain; so that if a user entered site2.com into their browser, they would be redirected to site1.com/directory/

I would have thought I could do this easily enough with creating a .htaccess file under /var/www, with the following;

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site1.com/directory/ [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately though, this doesn't seem to be taking any effect on the incoming request. Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Well i don't see anything wrong in your condition/rule. Is your htaccess at root level ?

Comment: @JustinIurman : there was no htaccess available initially, so I created the .htaccess file in nano, and stored it under /var/www/ ; as normal, public files/pages are available at /var/www/html/

Comment: Your htaccess has to be in your document root directory

Comment: Apologies - moved the .htaccess to the document root directory (/var/www/html/).. but unfortunately, still no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is set it up as a virtual host in Apache. Apache will then take care of showing the appropriate files for the site. 
This can be modified in your Apache config file.
Then when you type in www.site2.com it will be shown the correct files.

example

```
Server configuration

# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/site1
ServerName www.site1.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/site1.com/site2
ServerName www.site2.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Take a look at VHosts here.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Update:
Try adding the server alias.

```
ServerName   www.site2.com
ServerAlias  *.site2.com
```

Update 2:

Answering your comments. Here is another basic example. Alot more directives can go in there but you can decide that.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@site1.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ServerName site1.com
     ServerAlias www.site1.com
     ErrorLog /var/logs/httpd/site1-error_log
     CustomLog /var/logs/httpd/site1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@site2.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
     ServerName site2.com
     ServerAlias www.site2.com
     ErrorLog /var/logs/httpd/site2-error_log
     CustomLog /var/logs/httpd/site2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Then make sure you also have a `CNAME` DNS record for `www` pointing to @(your main site) of both sites. So that you can use www or without www to get to those sites if you want.

Here are step by step instructions. If it still won't work then something is up with your configuration.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/centos-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: Thanks - I updated my httpd conf with a new vhost, documentroot and servername, and restarted httpd - however, we still don't seem to be getting any redirect to the subdirectory.

Would it make a difference if the site was accessed without the www. prefix?

Comment: see my update. And see if that helps. Make sure the files are different and that you can tell you are looking at 2 different sites.

Comment: Do both sites as Vhosts. List the site1, and then under that do site2 as in the example.

Comment: strangely enough, when I added that, the subdirectory is no longer accessible? It gives a 404 error when attempting to access it via site1.com/site2/ - wheras the site2 url still directs traffic directly to site1.com. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still have those htaccess rules there? Take out any rewrite If config is setup correct it should work. What OS are you using BTW?

Comment: I killed off the htaccess rules - using CentOS6.5. Since adding site1 to the vhosts, I can access subdirectories again - however, still no redirecting taking place.

Comment: If you turn on VHosts all sites need to be listed. See the update.